# Mapping parabola onto itself.

Tags: linear-algebra

I need some help with mapping a parabola onto itself: the information i have is:
Consider the parabola $y=4x(x-1)$ over the domain [0,1]. The first key point is that each half of the parabola can be constructed from a transformed
copy of the whole via contraction, shearing and translation.The contraction clearly involves a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in the x -direction, but not necessarily in the y -direction. Hence for some a and b the contraction and vertical shearing matrices are of the form $\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 0\\
0 &a  
\end{bmatrix}$ and 
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  \\ 
 b&1   
\end{bmatrix}$. I need help setting up the question:

Given that, under these two successive matrix transformations, a point (x, y) on the parabola is mapped onto
another point on the same parabola, set up and solve simultaneous equations for a and b .

Comment: what do you mean exactly by half of the parabola?

Comment: The image of a point on the parabola must also satisfy the parabola’s equation. Pick two convenient-looking points.